# Access data from Vector3f

Tags: c++, ios

I was wondering why i am unable to do following:

`std::cout << myMesh.faces[i].vertices[k].pos[k];`

Error: `Type 'Vector3f' does not provide a subscript operator`

My struct:

```
struct ObjMeshVertex{
    Vector3f pos;
    Vector2f texcoord;
    Vector3f normal;
};
```

myMesh:

```
struct ObjMesh{
    std::vector<ObjMeshFace> faces;
};

struct ObjMeshFace{
    ObjMeshVertex vertices[3];
};
```

I cannot access the pos in any way.

Comment: What is `Vector3f` and what type is `myMesh`?

Comment: To two missing structs are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the `Vector3f` class does not have an `operator[](some integral type)`, which you are trying to use here:

```
myMesh.faces[i].vertices[k].pos[k]
                                ^ calling Vector3f::operator[](...)
```

Comment: Okay, i just realised that i have been sleeping while coding. My Vector3f is ofcourse defined with the 3dimensional coordinates and not an array.